# Google Sheets / Adding sum based on checkbox

Tags: google-sheets

I'm not sure if this is even possible but I'll try to explain.

I have a custom shoe business and trying to get organized with money.

Column 1 is just check boxes if a shoe was provided to me instead of me buying it for them.
Column 2 is the cost of the shoe
Column 3 is cost of the artwork
Column 4 is adding both costs as a sum of how much they owe me

So with that my question is...
is it possible to make it so if the check box under column 1 isn't checked then column 2 isn't added to column 4?

( I want to keep the cost of the shoe for my notes but don't want it added if I don't need to charge for it )

Sorry if this doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 0):

[image: check]

try this formula:

```
=index(if(B2:B<>"",B2:B+if(A2:A,C2:C,),))
```

Comment: Daniele, I may be wrong here; but as I understand the OP correctly, I think this is the intention: `=index(if(B2:B<>"",C2:C+if(A2:A,B2:B,),))`. However, this might be more clearly stated as follows: `=index(if(C2:C="",,C2:C+(B2:B*A2:A)))`.

Comment: `=index(if(B2:B<>"",C2:C+if(A2:A,B2:B,),))`  Yes, that is correct